# PWM square wave to DC voltage simple conversion

Tags: dc, pwm, filter, conversion

How do I convert a PWM square signal into a stable DC voltage (0V - 3.3V) in easiest and reliable way possible? (preferably in programming- microcontroller)

Comment: What is the frequency of the PWM? Could you low pass filter it?

Comment: Using a RC filter, but this is not preferred by you, since you want to program something.

Answer (score 0):

Using microcontroller - you can read PWM using timer and then output corresponding value to DAC. Look for microcontroller with integrated DAC, that would be the simplest way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But can I use the DC signal to generate an external interrupt? is it rising edge or falling edge configurable?

Comment: @Nikeboy, Re, "can I use the DC signal...?" Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as a DC signal. If it's truly DC, then it _never_ changes. Sounds like you need to provide a more complete description of the problem that you are trying to solve. What is the source of this "PWM square wave?" What do you intend to do with the "stable DC voltage?" etc.

Comment: @Nikeboy, you can use DACs output to trigger external interrupt in other system. This can be set to any - rising or falling edge. Although take care of initial output voltage of DAC, change from it may generate an unwanted interrupt.